# Return database array from function

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, class

Looking to see if there is a simple way of dumping out my results from a db query in a function.

The function:

```
function getAllCustomers() {
    global $mysqli;
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM customers");
    return $query;
}
```

This is in a class, so:

```
$customer = new Customer();
print_r($customer->getAllCustomers());
```

This shows:

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 10 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 24 [type] => 0 )
```

But I'm looking to return an array of all the fields and values for all rows.

I know I could run a foreach, but wasn't sure if there was an easier method?

Comment: If you take a look at the documentation for [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php), which is clearly what you are returning from the function, you should be able to answer this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `query` isn't the data itself, it's a [`mysql_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object. You can use its [`fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) method:

```
function getAllCustomers() {
    global $mysqli;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM customers");
    return $result->fetch_all();
}
```